# LLVM framework port to Java?

Tags: java, llvm

Is there any attempt in the works to make a Java version of LLVM?

Note: I am *not* asking about either LLVM front ends or back ends. I am asking about the LLVM toolset itself. I would like to experiment with LLVM but I find I am much more productive working with Java and Java libraries rather than C++.

Comment: JNA (I though you'd misspelled JNI for a moment there), that is a cool lib...

Comment: Are you talking about a LLVM language binding for Java?

Comment: I think so... the program input will be a user-defined language and the program output will be assembly for a particular processor, but I would like to use the LLVM algorithms and write my program in Java.

Answer (score 3):

There is a C interface to all LLVM libraries. It's quite stable and functional, and is used by Python and Haskell bindings.

So you can use it with JNI to create LLVM bitcode, optimize or transform it as you wish, save and run it, etc.